# Subtract value of the same column with different where clauses and various rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I Need help, I saw similar questions here, but no one helped me to solve this query.

I want to subtract values of the same column but with different where clauses but with various rows like this:

I Want to subtract this values so the output need to be like this:

Table with where clause 1

```
Product    |  Qty_totally| Name     
PRODUCT A     10           HORGE
PRODUCT B     20           OMINION
PRODUCT C     30           LIKT
```

Table with where clause 2

```
Product    |  Qty_totally| Name     
PRODUCT A     25           HORGE
PRODUCT B     50           OMINION
PRODUCT C     70           LIKT
```

Table with Final query

```
Product    |  Qty_totally| Name     
PRODUCT A     -15     HORGE
PRODUCT B     -30         OMINION
PRODUCT C     -40   LIKT
```

Help me please!!!!
I've tried this:

```
select descrição as 'Produto', sum(Quantidade_Total) as 'Quantidade_Entrada',Controle_armazem.Fornecedor as 'Fornecedor Controle Armazem' from Controle_armazem join produtos on controle_armazem.Modelo = produtos.idProdutos where Controle_armazem.Ativo = 1 and nota_fiscal is not null and nota_fiscal <> '' and defeito = 'Beneficiamento' AND situação = 'Beneficiado - Disponível para uso' GROUP BY descrição,Controle_armazem.fornecedor

Select descrição AS 'Produto', sum(Quantidade_Total) 'Quantidade Enviada', beneficiamento.Fornecedor as 'Fornecedor' From BeneficiamentoJoin controle_armazem On idPalete = palete join produtos on controle_armazem.Modelo = produtos.idProdutos WHERE Controle_armazem.Ativo = 1 And Beneficiamento.Ativo = 'A' GROUP BY descrição,Beneficiamento.fornecedor
```

I don't know how to subtract the value of "Quantidade_Total" column.

Comment: I tried to subtract the column value like select (select sum(value1) from table where table=1) - (select sum(value1) from table where table=2) group by name.  but the mysql return with syntax error

Comment: You should really provide sample input data (as text not images) and clearly mention what you want to do with it with expected output. There may be a better solution possible than one you'll (if at all) get now with incomplete information

Comment: _“Sorry for the bad format I'm new here”_ – then go read [ask] first of all, please. And then, use your _words_ to describe what you want to achieve, instead just referring to some images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So you want to subtract the quantities from query 2 from those of query 1. Why do you get 50 for PRODUCT B? Shouldn't this be -30?

Comment: Can it happen that there is a product in the results of query 1 and not in those of query 2 or vice versa? What do do in these situations?

Comment: Thorsten Kettner Yes can it happen not every record on the first 1 appears on the second query

Comment: Your edits have made your request much better to understand. It would be good if you added qualifiers to all columns in your queries. `descrição` is in `produtos` I suppose? And `Quantidade_Total`? And `nota_fiscal`, `defeito`, `situação`, `idPalete`, `palete`? You can use table aliases to get this more readable by the way (e.g. `Select ... b.Fornecedor as 'Fornecedor' From Beneficiamento b Join controle_armazem ca On ...`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd simply join both queries. As there can be products in query #1 that are not in the results of query #2 and vice versa, you'd want a full outer join that MySQL does not provide. The best approach should be then to select from the products table and outer join both queries to it.

```
select
  q1.product,
  coalesce(q1.qty_totally, 0) - coalesce(q2.qty_totally, 0) as qty_totally,
  q1.name as name1,
  q2.name as name2
from produtos p
left join (query #1 here) q1 on q1.product = p.descrição
left join (query #2 here) q2 on q2.product = p.descrição
where q1.product is not null or q2.product is not null;
```

Comment: BIG THANKS, but This is almost finished, Now I'm having a problem with that records that don't appear in the two tables. For Example: I have a product that appear on the second query, but not appear on the first query, but this query somehow make the subtract and appear a value , but this should appear 0 because that product just have 1 record , so this should be 2 - 0 = 2.

Comment: I mean that in this case Can be products in  query #1 that are not in the results of query #2 and vice versa. Other problem it's, in the cases that 1 product has 2 names, the query just show 1 name :(

Comment: Okay, you had forgotten to give us this information. It would have been good had you mentioned and shown this. (E.g. have a PRODUCT D in the first set and a PRODUCT E in the second and both in the results). I've updated my answer.

Comment: " you had forgotten to give us this information" sorry for that, but i still with the problem, a clear example: This query show me 'PRODUCT H' with 2 rows results, with two values -3676 of NAME A and -41 of NAME B, but there are no records in the table A of the 'PRODUCT H', this product just have records on the table b that are 5085. So there are 0 records on table A and 5085 on table B but the query show me -41, I can't understand why and how the query it's showing this value.
My group clause use 2 columns, PRODUCT AND NAME, so this product don't have any value of Name B in the table A.

Comment: As you group by product and name in both queries, you can have multiple rows for one product in their results. There are two ways to deal with this: 1. you really only want one row per product, so you'd group by product only instead and select one of the names, e.g. `MAX(beneficiamento.Fornecedor)`. 2. you do want multiple rows per product, so you must consider this in the joins. You'd add `and q2.fornecedor = q1.fornecedor` to the second `ON` clause in order to stay consistent.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the query 1 has 22 rows, and the query 2 has 40 rows, when I join this queries the results are inconsistent, because the query just join it, there something possible to do in this case?